# Signing AES Cipher

Tags: aes, diffie-hellman

Alice and Bob have a pre-shared long-term Ed25519 key used for veryfying/signing ephemeral keys.

They have a shared key which resulted from the DH exchange. They compute HKDF SHA256 of the shared key to use as the AES GCM key.

Should they sign the cipher to make sure a man in the middle didn't change it? If yes, is it safe to send the cipher + signature + HKDF salt in the same message?

Comment: But, he can still read the message, right, at least the first one before you detect.

Comment: In this context, if the attacker sent his public key to both, then yes. However, I'm signing the ephemeral public keys with a pre-shared long-term Ed25519 key to avoid this.

Comment: If you don't care that the attacker can read your messages, you don't need encryption, just send the messages with an authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCM is an authenticated encryption scheme; it allows Alice and Bob to detect if  messages have been tampered. If the DH exchange is authenticated, then you don't need to sign anything.

Comment: If the MitM attack is successful, he can read it change it. The OP newly revealed that they have  a pre-shared long-term Ed25519 key.